# Ошибка в выставлении внешнего ключа PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

Есть таблица комментариев к конкретному пользователю, в данной таблице необходимо хранить данные о комментаторе и о пользователе, оба столбца должны бы ссылаться на первичный ключ таблицы пользователей, но возникает данная ошибка. Не подскажете как решить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить запрос руками

```
ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_commented_by" FOREIGN KEY ("commented_by_id") REFERENCES "users" ("id") -- ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION -- (При необходимости можно добавить реакции на действия)
```

Возможно adminer создаёт ключи с одинаковым названием